# .htaccess 301 redirect with variables

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm upgrading a site which will use new links. It is possible to figure out the new URL from the old URL so I want to make a few 301 entries in the .htaccess to forward old links.

I'm aware that this is possible

```
Redirect 301 /orginalURL.html http://website.com/newURL.php
```

However I need to use portions of the old url to construct the new url. Is this possible?
Example old url

```
/index.php?page=/shop/bcat&c=47
```

And that should instead be

```
/se/category/47
```

In this case 47 is the key that I need to get from the old URL to the new. Also I can't expect /index.php to exist in all old links so they might look like /?page=/shop/bcat&c=47
as well.

Anyone who can help me here and I might be able to figure out the rest of the redirects myself :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use mod_rewrite to match against the query string. Try something like this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=/shop/bcat&c=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^/?(index.php)?$ http://website.com/se/category/%1? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: It did almost work as I wanted. The only thing was that the querystring is appended to the link I redirect to, resulting in the RewriteCond matching again, putting me in a loop. I tried to add the QSD flag but got this error: "RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters"

Comment: @Anders Sorry, there needs to be a `?` at the end of the URL: `http://website.com/se/category/%1?`. I've edited the answer.